# Initiate new phone call from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I'm listening for outgoing calls with my `BroadcastReceiver`.

When certain call is placed, specific number and/or conditions are met - that does not matter, I intercept the call.

After that I would like to like to place a new call, to another number. And here I get in trouble. Call is not placed - nothing happens - new activity is started but call is not initiated. Empty view and that's it.

By the way BroadcastReceiver receives intent, then `CallInitiatingActivity.onCreate()` is called and executed.

Broadcast listener

```
public class OutgoingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (conditionsAreMet()) {
            setResultData(null); //terminate current call
            Inetent intent = new Intent(context, CallInitiatingActivity.class)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Call initiating activity

```
public class CallInitiatingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Permission used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Suspicious log in debug level:

```
checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are missing.
```

I traced it to method in [this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/1e8a3579f8e49fd1f1a078d6be6864a6a8bac306/src/com/android/phone/PhoneUtils.java) at line #2074.

Comment: Updated question with "suspect log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question initiates new call normally.
But I could not see that because BroadcastReceiver receives intent with `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` action.

That is when I create `ACTION_CALL` and put extras to identify that I manually created a call that intent is "transformed" to another intent with `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` action. That way effectively loosing all added extras.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to ensure you have the right permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

and it might help to add

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

to the intent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, that I already added required permissions and flags are used in code. I'll update question with correct information.

Answer (score 0):

You define action for your BroadcastReceiver class in Manifest.xml like this

```
 <receiver android:name="yourBroadcastReceiverpackagename.BroadcastReceiverclassname" 
       android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
 <action 
       android:name="Declare your Action name here"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: What do you mean define action? Do I have to make another BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: no, you have to add your BroadcastReceiver class in Manifest.xml file

Comment: Hm. Maybe I as not clear in my question - I interrupt my original call, but another call is not placed.
My BroadcastReceiver (OutgoingCallListener) is declared in Manifest.xml